# canvas.height не принимается в качестве начального значения переменной

Tags: javascript, canvas, height

`var pos_y = canvas.height;` - такая запись не валидна (сразу весь холст становится чистым). При попытке задать высоту через `document.getElementById` тоже.

При этом методы `canvas` принимают `canvas.height`. Почему валидность кода перечёркивает даже такое безобидное как 
`var h = document.getElementById('drawingCanvas').clientHeight;`

```
var canvas;
    var context;
        window.onload = function() {
            canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");        
            setTimeout("drawFrame()", 300);         
        }   
            var pos_y = 200; // не принимает canvas.height

        function drawFrame(){           
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);           
            context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
            context.strokeStyle = 'yellow'
            context.fill();                         
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(canvas.width/2, pos_y, 30, 0,Math.PI*2, true);
            context.stroke();
             pos_y-=1;      
            setTimeout("drawFrame()", 300);    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var canvas;
    var context;
    var pos_y;
    window.onload = function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
        pos_y = canvas.height;
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");        
        setTimeout("drawFrame()", 300);         
    }
```